# Why is my post labelled “Homework”?

Tags: discussion

My question had nothing to do with home-work,  which the mods are well aware... as I had never alluded to it, nor am I enrolled in school. However  the mods falsely labelled my post out of spite from previous interactions we have had and is now sabotaging science out of their own pride and arrogance. Please see the post below and see for yourself. How can I flag the troll mods?

You can find the post here:

[Do fungi and bacteria use magnesium as a co-factor for the production of enzymes](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/88856/do-fungi-and-bacteria-use-magnesium-as-a-co-factor-for-the-production-of-enzymes)

Answer (score 8):

I'm sorry you feel upset about the status change of your post. I have commented under your post and I will cite it here for completeness:

> [...]'Homework' is used as a label to more generally describe Qs that are devoid of prior research. It borders on 'too broad', another much used close-reason. Your Q is also too broad. Prior research on OP's side can aid to lessen the scope and pinpoint a focused question. As of now it seems like a general metabolism question that warrants discussions on enzymes, co-factors, magnesium as a co-factor, the difference between general house-hold enzymes involved in glycolysis and CAC versus those used in detox mechanisms. It needs prior research and focus.

See for instance [this recent question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/88954/how-does-a-human-body-spend-energy-on-its-organs), which is a good example of a Q where the scope has been narrowed down effectively by adding prior research.

Regardless whether you agree with it or not, please stop calling the mods a troll. Further, David is neither a mod (mods have a ♦ behind their name), nor a troll. Instead, he is a long-term, hi-rep user who has earned many mod-privileges on this site. David can admittedly be a bit direct at times, but mind that he has been with us for a long time and knows better than most what the conventions of this site are and how these conventions came into being. Therefore I agreed with his close-vote, namely that the question is considered to be homework. The tag homework is indeed sometimes kind of unfortunate, as I have personally experienced here as well when a Q of mine was close-voted for that same reason while doing a postdoc :) There have been [meta discussions](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1818/rethinking-the-homework-close-reason) on this topic and they haven't resulted in another close-reason as yet. We are [kind of] working on that.

Comment: Thank you AliceD, I appreciate your honesty and kindness. I'm learning the ropes and have just updated my post.

Comment: @David - I've edited Q's title and edited the text in my A.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the title further. I really do think the "Homework" designation should be revisited. Is the problem a limit on the number of reasons for closing?

Comment: @David - the title looks great; the reason I don't (grossly) edit posts a lot is because people often don't like it, so I generally leave the content of posts alone. I hope I didn't offend you; that was the last thing that this post was meant to do. The homework tag - yes the tag is fine, but its scope is too broad and it offends people now and then. However, the number of complaints isn't too big, so it's been left alone for a while. I think we should get on it though. Perhaps a meta post is necessary to get this topic started again. Thanks David.

Comment: There have been about 100 meta posts on this already. Someone with the capability just needs to change it.

Comment: @canadianer I think there is still disagreement on what it should be changed *to*.

Comment: @BryanKrause I'm not sure it matters exactly what the close reason is changed to so long as it matches how it is actually being used. The math site [apparently already has a close reason that would be applicable](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1829/6307).

Comment: I have posted [a new question](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4010/proposal-for-rephrasing-the-homework-off-topic-explanation) with a proposal for changing the rubric on the close reason. I would welcome comment there.