# Handling low quality post queue

Tags: discussion

I am little confused about how to handle low quality post queue. I know there are already some posts like [this](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/783/what-should-be-done-with-questions-of-low-or-poor-quality) which try to answer this same question. However, I have moral dilemma.

1. On one hand, these questions are mostly homework and OP has done little or no research before asking.
2. But they are genuine questions and can help community in future

So shall I mark it for a 'closing (with appropriate reason)' or say 'looks okay' and comment on it.

Comment: I think this community is for very technical people so general homework questions should be set aside